# In-app billing RESTORE_TRANSACTION: Service Unavailable error

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I have a strange problem with in-app billing RESTORE_TRANSACTION command.

Every request RESTORE_TRANSACTION request sent to the Market return always RESPONSE_CODE=2 (SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE), And in logcat i find the following error:

```
06-14 09:49:40.689: E/Volley(9348): [13] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 429 for https://android.clients.google.com/vending/api/ApiRequest
06-14 09:49:40.689: E/Finsky(9348): [1] NotifyingErrorListener.onErrorResponse: Server error on InAppPurchaseInformationRequest: com.android.volley.ServerError
06-14 09:49:40.709: D/Finsky(9348): [1] MarketBillingService.sendResponseCode: Sending response RESULT_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE for request 5566380985346120640 to resistorcalc.main.
```

Until yesterday the RESTORE_TRANSACTION command worked. 
Now i read on other questions that it could be due to too many RESTORE_TRANSACTION requests sent to the market in a short time, and that could be the case in fact for an error during development yeterday i think i sent 40/50 requests in less than 1 minute.

But i thought that this could be a temporary problem, and i waited several hours. But now from yesterday i still receive the SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE error, and cannot test that command. Any help on how to solve that problem?

I also tried to remove the published draft from the market, replacing it with an updated version. I also uninstalled the application from the device and installed it again from scratch, but with no luck. 
Any idea? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably just have to wait a bit more. It's either a temporary block, or a Google-side problem. You can try testing with at different Google account to see if that makes a difference. Also, make sure you cache market responses and issue RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS only when the app is installed for the first time.

Comment: I tried with another phone and it worked, then i tried again with my phone and now it works. Thanks.